# Getting connection timeout from get request of Request module of Python

Tags: python, request, timeout

I am new to Python and am getting he following error. However, the same piece is working perfectly when I run it in postman. Infact, the below code has been taken from Postman's code option itself and I have just removed the postman token from the headers. Am I doing something wrong?

```
File "addusers.py", line 20, in addusers
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 68, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
 raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='something.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pod/test/i0HkG6dA/list (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x2464450>, 'Connection to something.com timed out. (connect timeout=50)'))
```

My code is as follows:

```
import requests

url = "https://something.com/pod/test/iFoFA6dA/list"
headers = {
'sessionToken': "1ae9234fb9c7a4901992",
'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
#    'Postman-Token': "d1cf7cf5-9b56-42bf-be39-4e534f41325f"
}
print("hi")
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
print("bye")
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Is the response different when you include the Postman token?

Comment: No, the response does not change. Also, Postman token changes everytime I run the query in Postman so I guess its just a session token kind of value for postman.

Comment: is that the correct port, you are using the default 443??
You can also check if it is a get method (also use requests.get instead of requests.request)